# Magneto 2 : How to get quote id in order create page admin?

Tags: magento2, admin, quote

Magento 2 i want qoute id in order crete  page admin, but i got null in quote id.
I'm Using **Magento\Checkout\Model\Session**

> $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the admin quote session you need to use

- \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote

See

```
  public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $quoteSession,
   
  ) {

      $this->_session = $quoteSession;
  }

  public function getSession()
  {
      return $this->_session;
  }

  /**
   * Retrieve quote object model
   *
   * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
   */
  public function getQuote()
  {
      if (!$this->_quote) {
          $this->_quote = $this->getSession()->getQuote();
      }

      return $this->_quote;
  }
```